Is a passive device that outputs as polarized light more than 50% of incoming randomly polarized light impossible?
Is it possible to design a passive device that takes in  randomly polarized (nearly) monochromatic light and outputs more than half of it polarized? If not, why not?
My idea would be: Have a polarizer that instead of absorbing reflects wrongly polarized light. Reflect it back to something akin to an integrating sphere, where I'd expect the polarization to become essentially random again. A portion of this light then comes back to the polarizer, and almost half of it could be emitted again.
Is there some physical reason why this is not possible?

Well, first of all: why? :)
But now getting onto the question.
I can think of the following scenario
You take your light and use a polarizing beam splitter: now you have 2 channels, with all the light and it's polarized. You can now pass one of the channels -- lets call it channel 2 -- through a quarter-wave plate, turning the light into circular polarization, and now re-combine the two channels with another polarizing beam splitter. So that channel 1 is completely transmitted and channel 2 is 50:50 transmitted/reflected. As long as the arm length difference between these two channels is longer than the coherence length of your light, it should in principle now look like an incoherent source with a defined polarization and more than 50% of the in-coupling light.
Now you could repeat the process from the rejected port from channel 2: quarter-wave plate and recombine, which now further boosts the output of your device. Due to losses and the differential increments of the setup you cannot get 100%, but as you see from the setup, you can get pretty high pretty fast.
